# In diagrams.net (draw.io), how to hide a tag by default?

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

I have a diagram with multiple tags, some of them visible and some hidden. There are buttons with toggles for specific tags. However, when I export the diagram to html, every tag becomes visible by default, and it becomes a mess.

I can add a reset button which prepares the diagram by hiding the tags that need to be hidden, but it still needs to be clicked manually.

Is there a way to make sure a tag is hidden at first when the diagram gets opened? Or a way to autorun a link action that does it?

Comment: I'm interested in a real answer but here is what i do actually:
I put a big blank rectangle on all my diagram
I set all the shapes i want to hide under the rectangle
I set all the shapes i want to display above the rectange
On loading only the right tags are displayed and the the users can use the buttons